# Hibernate avoid uncessary update statement

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I know that Oracle treat an empty string as an null value. So if I do a batch job to update an Entity with new values, then **Hibernate/Oracle** will do an update statement, for example if I set an empty string value to an attribute value. But if I do this indirectly like in this method **updateStringContainerIndirect** then nothing happens. Why is this so?

Say I have following entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class StringContainer {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String stringValue;

    @Version
    private int entityVersion;

    //Getter Setter...
}
```

Here is my TestClass:

```
public class StringTest {

    private static Repository repository;
    private List<StringContainer> stringContainerValues;

    @Before
    public void loadData() {
        stringContainerValues = repository.getStringContainers();
        for (StringContainer stringContainer : stringContainerValues) {
            stringContainer.setStringValue("");
        }
    }

    @After
    public void clearData() {
        stringContainerValues = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void updateStringContainerDirectIncrementVersionNumber() {
        for (StringContainer stringContainer : stringContainerValues) {
            long oldEntityVersion = stringContainer.getEntityVersion();
            updateStringContainerDirect(stringContainer, "");
            Assert.assertEquals(oldEntityVersion++, stringContainer.getEntityVersion());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void updateStringContainerNoIncrementVersionNumber() {
        for (StringContainer stringContainer : stringContainerValues) {
            long oldEntityVersion = stringContainer.getEntityVersion();
            updateStringContainerIndirect(stringContainer, "");
            Assert.assertEquals(oldEntityVersion, stringContainer.getEntityVersion());
        }
    }

    public void updateStringContainerDirect(StringContainer stringContainer, String newValue) {
        stringContainer.setStringValue(newValue);
    }

    public void updateStringContainerIndirect(StringContainer stringContainer, String newValue) {
        String dbString = stringContainer.getStringValue();
        dbString = newValue;
        stringContainer.setStringValue(dbString);
    }
}
```